# What is the least privilege an account needs to open a pssession to a windows server

Tags: powershell, remote-access

I'm looking to create an account with which I can connect to a windows server using PSsession (powershell)

What is the least privilege that is needed to have a PSsession open for that server?

At this moment only Admins are able to create a PSsession on that server.

Comment: take a look at these two articles ... PowerShell Remoting without administrator rights – 4sysops — https://4sysops.com/archives/powershell-remoting-without-administrator-rights/ ---&--- How to Configure Windows Remote PowerShell Access for Non-Privileged User Accounts – GSX Help Center — https://helpcenter.gsx.com/hc/en-us/articles/202447926-How-to-Configure-Windows-Remote-PowerShell-Access-for-Non-Privileged-User-Accounts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a non-administrator account needs to use PowerShell Remote, that is what the Remote Management Users group is for.